# Get the last row in Slick

Tags: sql, postgresql, scala, slick

I have PostgreSQL table.

Messages:

```
 |id  |  phone | message | login |
-----------------------------------
* |1   | 85543422 | Hello!  | User1 |
  |2   | 85543422 | i love  | User2 |
-----------------------------------*
```

I need to filter the table by phone value (85543422) and get the username from the last row.
Now I have a method that allows you to pull the username from the first line.

```
//return "User1"
    def getUserByPhone():String = {  
          val query = outgoing.filter(_.phone === "85543422").map(_.login).result.headOption
          val result = Await.result(db.run(query), Duration.Inf)
          if (result.value.isEmpty) return "None"
          result.value.get
      }
```

Help with the implementation of the method for removing the user name from the last line.
I need get "User2"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may sort by id desc to get the username on the last row

eg

```scala
 val query = outgoing.filter(_.phone === "85543422")
                     .sortBy(_.id.desc)
                     .map(_.login).result.headOption
```

Comment: Waw! This is nice idea! Okey, I try it.